# Perf: cache-misses are not mapped for AMD family 17h processors

Tags: linux, perf, amd-processor

I'm trying to performance measure some code on `AMD` Epyc processor, with Linux kernel 5.4.80:

```
# lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          128
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-127
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              64
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           49
Model name:                      AMD EPYC 7702P 64-Core Processor
Stepping:                        0
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1597.858
CPU max MHz:                     2000.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1500.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3992.43
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       2 MiB
L1i cache:                       2 MiB
L2 cache:                        32 MiB
L3 cache:                        256 MiB
...
#
```

It turns out that certain events are not directly mapped to the hardware events, but instead are [mapped to generic hardware events](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.80/source/arch/x86/events/amd/core.c#L244).

When I run for example `perf stat -e cache-misses ...` what does it report then? How much I can trust those reported values, what do they actually represent?

In my case, am I better off to use raw counter values instead of relying on `perf` names?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your cpu model (full name of the cpu, `lscpu |grep -i model`)? The mapping was added in https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=155320296909863&w=2, and it was not updated in other patches as I see. Yes, better use non-generic cache events from `perf list`: https://protools19.github.io/slides/Eranian_KeynoteSC19.pdf#page=25 "Always prefer actual PMU events to  generic versions○Know what you want to measure" & "What does cache-misses (Linux generic event) eventmeasure?○At what cache level? For load or stores? For code or data? Speculative accesses?○Hardware prefetchers? Software prefetches"

Comment: @osgx, thanks for feedback. I updated my question with CPU model information. When they say _Always prefer actual PMU events to generic versions_ do they recommend to use specific events in `perf list` output? For example, those marked as **[Hardware cache event]**

Comment: Mark, you can use hardware events from `perf list` or encode the event code as raw event (manually or with andikleen/pmu-tools jevents). With non-generic events from perf list and with raw events you can check the actual event being counted (there should be some verbose option to print it from perf list or perf record). But with generic event name like "cache-misses" you trust author of generic mapping and this mapping is only available as source code you linked (perf_event_open will use generic code and kernel will reencode to raw inside kernel code). This is how I understand google's advice.